# How to initialize a class variable as an empty array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I essentially just want to assign the default value of a class variable to an empty array.

I've tried the following, but did not have any luck:

```
class Test {
    constructor(myArray = []) {
        this.myArray = myArray;
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as when I try to print Test.myArray, undefined is returned rather than an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access Prototype, your class is initialized correctly, just do:

```js
class Test {
    constructor(myArray = []) {
        this.myArray = myArray;
    }
}

const t = new Test();

console.log(t.myArray)
```

`new` keyword means, that you are creating a new *instance* of the Test class.

Comment: This solution is correct. It was my mistake for forgetting to create an instance of the class.